# Cannot install python3-setuptools

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools

I am using python 3.4.3.

When I try to run this code on terminal (once I'm already inside the respective folder)

```
pip3 install python3-setuptools
```

I get this error message:

```
Collecting python3-setuptools
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3 setuptools (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for python3-setuptools
```

Could anyone help me out on this?

Comment: I don't get your question. what are you trying to do. Your title says "Levenshtein package installation Error" but in the body of your question you say you have installed it already and are then running `pip3 install python3-setuptools` but it is not clear why you are doing that and what you are expecting to happen and how it is related to your trying to install Levenshtein

Comment: I have installed it but I can't import it in python. I get an import error module not found...not sure why :/ So I was wondering could it be something else that I haven't done right

Comment: I get this msg on terminal as well `-bash levenshtein: pip3 install levenshtein`
`Collecting levenshtein
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement levenshtein (from versions: )`
No matching distribution found for levenshtein.    I don't know why but something is wrong with the levenshtein package...it seems not to have been installed properly?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install `python3-setuptools` with `pip` — there is no such pip-installable package: https://pypi.org/project/python3-setuptools/ — error 404. In python ecosystem the package is called simply [setuptools](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/).

`python3-setuptools` is the name of the package in Debian/Ubuntu package system:

https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python3-setuptools&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3-setuptools&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all

So either you install it with `apt install python3-setuptools` or `pip3 install setuptools`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try that out :) Sorry a bit noob here